# Writing Unix line ending when using Groovy template engine on Windows

Tags: java, groovy, line-endings

I am using Groovy Template engine to generate some scripting code. It calls this at the end to render each file.

```
template.writeTo(output.newWriter())
```

output variable is of type java.io.File

Groovy Doc - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-1.7.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/io/File.html#newWriter()

Unfortunately this writes the new line character depending on the platform where we are running the template engine (Windows - \r\n, Unix - \n)

I couldn't find a way to override it so that it always writes Unix line endings. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature of Java that uses platform-dependent line separators.  You can override which line separator to actually use by setting the `line.separator` property.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()

Groovy uses the `line.separator` property by default, but can be configured in the Groovy template engine separately.

http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#markuptemplate-config